# JavaMail how to close connection after some email

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

How can I close underlying SMTP connection after it served specific count of email to SMTP?

We are using [smtp-connection pool](https://github.com/nithril/smtp-connection-pool). I'm not sure in which class the connection object resides. Transport or session?

Answer (score 2):

It's in Transport, you can use

```
transport.close();
```

Comment: We are using apache commons pool like this ` try (ClosableSmtpConnection transport = connPool.borrowObject()) {...}`. Would you think it is possible to create pool eviction strategy for that pool, that will evict transports used more the couple of times or created specified time ago? This should ensure close of long opened connections and also close of heavy used SMTP connections.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Declare the factory and the connection pool, usually at the application startup
SmtpConnectionPool smtpConnectionPool = new SmtpConnectionPool(SmtpConnectionFactoryBuilder.newSmtpBuilder().build());

//borrow an object in a try-with-resource statement or call `close` by yourself
try (ClosableSmtpConnection transport = smtpConnectionPool.borrowObject()) {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(transport.getSession());
    MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, false);
    mimeMessageHelper.addTo("to@example.com");
    mimeMessageHelper.setFrom("from@example.com");
    mimeMessageHelper.setSubject("Hi!");
    mimeMessageHelper.setText("Hello World!", false);
    transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage);
}

//Close the pool, usually when the application shutdown
smtpConnectionPool.close();
```

Comment: What if I need to close the connection every 20 emails to enable loadbalancing SMTP servers properly.

Comment: try () will close ClosableSmtpConnection

Comment: Does it close the socket connection after each message?Or only SMTP connection? I tried some test and the physical connection stayed open.

Comment: It's using Connection Pool 
@Override
  public void close() throws Exception {
    objectPool.returnObject(this);
  }